# How to process rendered result of a child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a React component that scans through the elements of its child component and renders itself based on that.

Imagine I have many components, each with `h1`, `h2`, and `p` tags. I would like to create a generic table of contents component that can be used as a parent component to these other components. The table of contents component would need to render the child page and then scan through it for the `h1`/`h2` tags and render to a table of contents.

So my question is how do I scan through the "DOM" of the child component after I've created it using `React.createElement()` in the parent component?

Printing the result of this call, I only see an object with `key`, `props`, `ref`, and `type` attributes, which don't seem to fit the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the others' answers I've used their ideas of reading from the DOM after the first render. Instead of `useEffect` I am using [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) so that it doesn't trigger before the first render. Using `querySelectorAll` I'm able to get the heading tags, then get their text using `.innerText`.

Here is what I ended up with:

```js
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import TableOfContents from './TableOfContents';

const TableOfContentsPage = ({ children }) => {

    const [headings, setHeadings] = useState([]);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const pageContents = document.getElementById('toc-page-parent');
        setHeadings(Array.from(pageContents.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5')));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <TableOfContents headings={headings} />
            <div id='toc-page-parent'>{children}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TableOfContentsPage;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

// Headings is an array of DOM elements
const TableOfContents = ({ headings }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
        <ul>
            {headings.map(heading => <li key={heading.innerText}>{heading.innerText}</li>)}
            // can check heading.tagName to see if it's H1/H2/H3/H4/H5
        </ul>
    </div>
);

export default TableOfContents;
```

Usage:

```
<TableOfContentsPage>
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <h2>hi2</h2>
  <h3>hi3</h3>
</TableOfContentsPage>
```

Result:
[image: result of code]

Of course, I can easily adjust the indentation in the TOC based on the heading level, by using [`.tagName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp) on the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

React.createElement doesn't actually create a DOM element you can access but rather an object that React understands how to convert into a DOM element when rendering. You probably want to add an effect that runs on re-render and scans through child elements. It will probably look something like this

```js
function TableOfContents(_props) {
  const { elements } = props;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const childElements = document.getElementById("parent")?.children
    // you could also possibly just use elements directly instead of getting the parent first
    if (childElements) {
      // do something with children elements
    }
  }, [elements])

  return (
    <div id="parent">
      {props.elements.map(e => React.createElement(e))}
    </div>
  )
}

// usage of Component
<TableOfContents elements={['h1', 'h1', 'h2', 'p']} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't get how page contents are added in this example though, did you mean `<TableOfContents elements={[<h1>hello</h1>, <h1>world</h1>, <h2>etc</h2>, <p>etc</p>]} />`? 
The way I had in mind of using it was something like `<TableOfContents contents={Page1} />` where `Page1` renders to a bunch of `h1`s and `p`s. I think using a combination of this and the other answer will work though :)

Comment: Yes you would need more to actually render content, this was just for example sake.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you have control over the generation of those h1, p and other tags, then use that data source for your TOC generation algorithm.

For example, your content might be generated by a remote data source. If so, use the same data source instead of scanning DOM.

But if you don't have access to it, then you have to scan the Dom. To do it create a component and use the hook, `useEffect`. In that hook you can run DOM queries like `document.getElementsByTagName` function to find out those tags. The elements returned by functions in document object are real DOM elements not react vdom elements.

```
function TOC({pageId}) {

   let [tocItems, setTocItems] = useState ();
   useEffect (()=> {
       let els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
       // Do something with elements and set it for the state
       // setTocItems ();
   },[pageId]);
       
   return (
        <div>{tocItems}</div>
   );
}
```

Comment: The contents of the page (h1s and such) are "hardcoded" but different for each page, so I'm not sure how to pick that out. Thank you for the example and `document.getElementsByTagName('p')`, I think I could fit this in.

Comment: If I use the same TOC component with multiple page components (think of allowing flipping to a next page), this won't re-render right?

Comment: To that use the dependency array of react hook. Currently im using empty array. Add something like page is which you pass as a prop. Then whenever this page is changes component will Re render. I've updated the code.